# Firebase user`s online status

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making mobile app with include firabase connection. I'd like to handle user online status. First idea was to set status from app : online onAppStart and offline onClising, but we all known that app can be closed in wrong way, and then status wont be updated.

I found something like this:

```
firebase.database().ref(".info/connected");
```

Will it work as I want if i set this somewhere in firebase-function module? Is it the best options to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the **presence** mechanism in the Realtime Database.

Have a look at:

- [How To Build a Presence System](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html) (Firebase blog)
- [Using presence in Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence#using_presence_in_realtime_database)

Comment: Seems great, I will try this one